# How to detect i18N UI issues in Android

Tags: android, testing, user-interface, robotium, robolectric

What kind of tools and techniques you use to detect UI issues for internationalized applications in android ?? We know that languages like German takes more space then english, this may cause issues in applications user interface like alignment, overflow etc, how do we detect this ??

Take this example:

[image: 2 text View in English]

2 text View in English

[image]

Same textview in German

In german the ui is changed. How can 1 detect this changes ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public boolean searchText(String text,
                 int minimumNumberOfMatches,
                 boolean scroll,
                 boolean onlyVisible)
Searches for the specified text and returns true if the searched text is found a specified number of times.
Parameters:
text - the text to search for. The parameter will be interpreted as a regular expression.
minimumNumberOfMatches - the minimum number of matches expected to be found. 0 matches means that one or more matches are expected to be found
scroll - true if scrolling should be performed
onlyVisible - true if only texts visible on the screen should be searched
Returns:
true if text is found a specified number of times and false if the text is not found
```

If you use with right parameters this instruction it returns false when all string is not displayed.

The second solution is to take screenshot for all screens and analyze them to identify problems in layout.

Comment: thanks Flavio, screenshot might not be scalable option, for the first method can you give some implementation details.

Comment: solo.searchtext(solo.getString("String_id_from_strings.xml", 0, false, true)); you've to substitute String_di_from_strings.xml with id for that string present int the file.